# lmer pairwise comparisons for 3 variables interactions, holm correcting for few planned comparisons instead of 28

Tags: r, lme4, p-value, emmeans, pairwise

I have 3 IVs: Within --> Hand(left,right), Time(pre,post); Between --> Training (treatment, sham) and a continuous DV: RT.

I have run a linear mixed effect model to see if there are significant interactions using this line:

```r
model1 = lmer(RT ~ Training*Time*Hand + (1|Sub), data = db)
```

Then I want to see the differences between some of the levels (i.e., treatment-before-left and treatment-after-left) and adjust the pvalues using the Holm method. However, I do not want to correct for "illogic" comparisons such as treatment-before-left vs sham-after-right.

The line I used was this:

```r
emmeans(model1, list(pairwise ~ Hand * Time * Training), adjust="holm")
```

I thought of using `adjust = "none"` and adjusting later for the planned comparisons but I don't know how to do that in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give a reproducible examples, but your strategy of computing unadjusted p-values, extracting a subset, and doing the Holm adjustment yourself sounds sensible — the two things you need to know are (1) how to extract the p-values from an `emmeans` object (see below) and (2) how to compute adjusted p-values (answer: `p.adjust(., "holm")`: this is a base-R function).

```
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ factor(carb), mtcars)
e1 <- emmeans(m1, list(pairwise ~ carb), adjust = "none")
pval1 <- as.data.frame(e1$pair)$p.value
e2 <- emmeans(m1, list(pairwise ~ carb), adjust = "holm")
pval2 <- as.data.frame(e2$pair)$p.value
all.equal(pval2, p.adjust(pval1, "holm"))  ## TRUE
```